# Why is one of the following always true in a given matrix A?

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, duality-theorems

Consider A, a given matrix. I want to show that exactly one of the following holds:

1) $\exists  x\neq 0$ such that $Ax=0$

2) $\exists  p$ such that $p^TA>0$

I tried proving that this is equivalent to Farkas' Lemma, but I couldn't really get anywhere. I also tried writing an LP problem and its dual to see if I get somewhere, but I don't know what to use as the vector in my objective function.

Comment: What is $p$ and how does $p^T$ have a size?

Comment: Do 1) and 2) hold for $A=\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\1&1\end{bmatrix}$?

Comment: Then I am confused how you are defining multiplication... let $p$ be a vector with positive entries. Then doing whatever $p^{T}A$ is supposed to mean should be positive (since it's just multiplication and addition of positive terms I assume). I say whatever $p^{T}A$ is supposed to mean since I would think $p^{T}A$ would yield a vector instead of a number (unless $0$ represents the zero vector... but then what is the ordering...?)